# Ansible ec2_remote_facts

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using ec2_remote_facts to find the ec2 facts of an instance based on the tags.

```
- name: Search ec2
  ec2_remote_facts:
    filters:
  "tag:Name": "{{hostname}}"
  aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
  aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
  region: "{{aws_region}}"
  register: ec2_info
```

Now I want to get the instance id of the instance id of that particular host and store it in a variable to use it in my playbook.

Can someone please help in finding or extracting the instance id.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use your registered variable 'ec2_info':

```
- debug: var=ec2_info
- debug: var=item
  with_items: ec2_info.instance_ids
# register new variable
- set_fact:
     instance_ids: ec2_info.instance_ids
- add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=ec2hosts
  with_items: ec2_info.instances

- name: wait for instances to listen on port:22
  wait_for:
    state=started
    host={{ item.public_dns_name }}
    port=22
  with_items: ec2_info.instances

# Connect to the node and gather facts,
# including the instance-id. These facts
# are added to inventory hostvars for the
# duration of the playbook's execution

- hosts: ec2hosts
  gather_facts: True
  user: ec2-user
  sudo: True
  tasks:
# fetch instance data from the metadata servers in ec2
- ec2_facts:

# show all known facts for this host
- debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]

# just show the instance-id
- debug: msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_ec2_instance-id'] }}"
```

Comment: This code snipped has messed indentation and may be confusing for newcomers. First part is a list of tasks (without play header like `hosts` etc) and second part has play header, but tasks indentation is incorrect. I advice to split this code block into two – the first will be task list from some larger play, and the second will be a play with corrected tasks indentation.

Comment: See also the "-v" flag for verbose output to see the data structure that will be stored in a register. --Somewhat easier than adding debug statements if you only need to know the structure of return type.